# Bean validation not working in JSF

Tags: jsf-2, bean-validation

I have a JSF 2.2 page using Primefaces and input text. I want to apply bean validation on the Beans so that I don't need to change every single page. Unfortunately, the constraints seem not to be fired. Example:

```
<p:inputText id="year" value="#{userSession.year}" >
```

And the backend:

```
@SessionScoped
@Named
public class UserSession implements Serializable {

    @Min(value=1900, message="Year must be > 1900") @Max(value=2020, message="Year must be < 2020")
    int year;
    . ..
}
```

What could be the reason why the @Mix and @Max constraint is not kicking in ?
Thanks

Comment: Are you working with Tomcat or a Java EE compatible application server ? and wich version ?

Comment: I beg your pardon for the late reply. I'm working on WildFly 8.2 application server.

Comment: no worries, could you provide more info about your import statements?

Comment: Sure: import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped; import javax.validation.constraints.Max; import javax.validation.constraints.Min;

Comment: Ever find a solution? Same boat.